Decompression is disabled for this tree
The following is my merkle tree config for cnft using metaplex bubblegum (solana devnet)
{
  treeConfig: {
    publicKey: 'Hu4Rqtx2sf5gGKEYkY6TXPxMjUqGQUnASKZ2gCvxXtcZ',
    header: {
      executable: false,
      owner: 'BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY',
      lamports: [Object],
      rentEpoch: 18446744073709551616n,
      exists: true
    },
    discriminator: [
      122, 245, 175, 248,
      171,  34,   0, 207
    ],
    treeCreator: 'EVDVp1miKUdGR3Y9PcckUAxmXNaZNS85AHchJaaKFkh9',
    treeDelegate: 'EVDVp1miKUdGR3Y9PcckUAxmXNaZNS85AHchJaaKFkh9',
    totalMintCapacity: 8n,
    numMinted: 3n,
    isPublic: true,
    isDecompressible: 1
  }
}

And when I try to redeem the voucher with

    const assetWithProof = await getAssetWithProof(umi, assetId)

    await redeem(umi, {
        ...assetWithProof,
        leafOwner: keypairSigner,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi)

I get the error that 'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: DecompressionDisabled. Error Number: 6033. Error Message: Decompression is disabled for this tree..',
I cannot understand why this is happening since in the treeConfig it is clearly visible that decompression is set to be true?

From the listing you provided here, I assume that says the compression is disabled.
See the code that throws the error here:
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum/blob/main/programs/bubblegum/program/src/processor/redeem.rs#L60
The TreeConfig account defines the Disabled state to be coded as value 1
See:
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum/blob/main/programs/bubblegum/program/src/state/mod.rs#L86

Okayy, that was little odd using 1 as false value. Thank you for addressing!
Can you please suggest how to enable the decompression?

I assume with the instruction SetDecompressibleState https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum/blob/main/programs/bubblegum/program/src/processor/set_decompressible_state.rs

I am using their instructions mentioned in official docs for creating the tree:
`const builder = await createTree(umi, {
merkleTree,
maxDepth: 3,
maxBufferSize: 8,
public: true,
SetDecompressibleState: 0
// treeCreator: keypairSigner
})It does not recogniseSetDecompressibleState` variable. Do you have any further idea?

The state is configured at the creation for Disabled as you can check in the code:
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum/blob/main/programs/bubblegum/program/src/processor/create_tree.rs#L59
I think the SetDecompressibleState: 0 does nothing in your code as there is no such variable expected. More on that you use upper case S while the other items work with lower case. More of that it signals that usage of the SetDecompressibleState: 0 in the call is artificial.

Yes, I realize that. I only put it there for the reference. I have tried with multiple possible values for decompression that could be possible inspiring from the link you mentioned, it expects none of those values. Is it possible that they have bug on their side or I am missing out on something?

I expect it's the behaviour that is intentional. Why don't you call the other instruction setDecompressibleState after the tree is created?
